# How to make simple combobox with selected value in XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox, selectedvalue

What is the correct syntax to select a combobox item with *value* (not index) in pure XAML?

**Doesn't work:**

```
<StackPanel>
    <ComboBox SelectedValue="CA">
        <ComboBoxItem Tag="CO">Colorado</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem Tag="CA">California</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem Tag="NM">New Mexico</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
</StackPanel>
```

**Doesn't work:**

```
<StackPanel>
    <ComboBox SelectedValue="CA">
        <ComboBoxItem Value="CO">Colorado</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem Value="CA">California</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem Value="NM">New Mexico</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
</StackPanel>
```

**Even this doesn't work:**

```
<ComboBox SelectedValue="Colorado">
    <ComboBoxItem Tag="CO">Colorado</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Tag="CA">California</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Tag="NM">New Mexico</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

**This doesn't work:**

```
<StackPanel>
    <ComboBox SelectedItem="CA">
        <ComboBoxItem Tag="CO">Colorado</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem Tag="CA">California</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem Tag="NM">New Mexico</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think this should work. Have a try.

```
<StackPanel>
    <ComboBox>
        <ComboBoxItem Tag="CO">Colorado</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem Tag="CA" IsSelected="True">California</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem Tag="NM">New Mexico</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: ComboBoxItem doesn't have a "Value" property.

Comment: oh I'm sorry, should be Tag, not value, was a mistake by me

Answer (score 5):

```
<ComboBox SelectedValuePath="Content" SelectedValue="{Binding Source="...", Path="..."}">
   <ComboBoxItem Content="..." isSelected="true"/>
   <ComboBoxItem Content="..." />
   <ComboBoxItem Content="..." />
</ComboBox>
```

It should work with content, tag... or any other property you'd like to bind.

Answer (score 2):

```
<StackPanel>
    <ComboBox AllowDrop="True">
        <ComboBoxItem Tag="CO">Colorado</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem Tag="CA" IsSelected="True">California</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem Tag="NM">New Mexico</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
</StackPanel>
```

You need to set AllowDrop="True" for the combobox and isselected for the item.

Answer (score 1):

The ComboBox element has a `SelectedItem` property, maybe this is the one you need.